# mysql error on query (add_date error) using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this mysql statement and it's giving me error:

```
INSERT INTO envios ( fecha_estimada_entrega) VALUES (ADDDATE('15/10/2011', INTERVAL 8    DAY));
```

When i run it i get this meesage:

```
#1048 - Column 'fecha_estimada_entrega' cannot be null
```

Can you please help me out on this?

I'm sure it's quite simple, but my head is burned.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your date format to the standard [ISO 8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO8601):

```
INSERT INTO envios (fecha_estimada_entrega)
VALUES (ADDDATE('2011-10-15', INTERVAL 8 DAY));
```

MySQL is probably trying to parse 15 as a month number, failing, and converting your `'15/10/2011'` date to NULL. Switching to ISO 8601 (the one true date format BTW) gets me sensible results:

```
mysql> select ADDDATE('2011-10-15', INTERVAL 8 DAY);
+---------------------------------------+
| ADDDATE('2011-10-15', INTERVAL 8 DAY) |
+---------------------------------------+
| 2011-10-23                            |
+---------------------------------------+
```

As an aside, you should always use ISO 8601 date and time formats internally and limit other formats to the edges (i.e. user input and final display). You'll save yourself a lot of trouble that way and they'll even sort properly as strings.

Comment: That solved it thanks. I guess i still have to learn about date formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a date format which MySQL understands (ex. Y-M-D).

```
INSERT INTO envios ( fecha_estimada_entrega )
VALUES ( ADDDATE('2011-10-15', INTERVAL 8 DAY) );
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't know about that alternative.. I've always used `DATE_ADD`. Updated to match the question.